# How to convert variadic function arguments into collection such as Set or List

Tags: java, collections, variadic-functions

In Java, we can use variadic function in the following way:

```
public Set packStrings(String...strings){
    for (String str : strings){
         //Do something on the str
    }

    //How to convert strings into a Set?
}
```

My question is, what is the type of "strings"? is it String[]?
How to put the string(s) denoted by the "strings" into Java Collection, such as Set or List?

Please kindly advise.

Thanks & regards,
William Choi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a string array, so you can do:

```
Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Comment: @William Choi  Yes. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 2):

```
public Set<String> packStrings(String...strings){

    //Way 1 to create List
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : strings){
         //adding to list
         strList.add(str);
    }
    //way 2 to create List
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strings);
    //converting to set from List
    Set<String> setStr= new HashSet<String>(strList);
    return setStr;
}
```

Have a look at this [Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: life.java You need to return setStr ;) and specify the generic in the method definition.